# my android phone can not run when "LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true" in makefile

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, arm, neon

the appliction abort when i add `LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true` in android.mk, even without any neon instructions. some words like "-mfpu=neon" alse cause abort.

my phone is motorola android2.2
is my configuration in Android NDK not correct? or my phone arm can not support neon instructions? i need to run neon instructions on my phone.

help me!!!thanks!!!

ps:
application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_MODULES := AudioEngine
```

android.mk:

```
CC = $(BASE_PATH)/build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-gcc 
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
LOCAL_MODULE    := AudioEngine
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := AudioEngine.cpp Effecter.cpp SoundTouch.cpp TDStretch.cpp RateTransposer.cpp AAFilter.cpp BPMDetect.cpp \
FIFOSampleBuffer.cpp FIRFilter.cpp mmx_optimized.cpp PeakFinder.cpp sse_optimized.cpp cpu_detect_x86.cpp fft.s\
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: which hw/phone exactly is that?

Comment: btw this one is pretty nice to check cpu features https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.gatech.cc.cpuid&hl=en

Comment: If neon does not work on your phone, it is indeed very likely that neon is not supported on your phone.

Comment: I believe the default configuration for the compiler is Thumb2 instructions when set to output to ARMv7. If you're using an older ARMv6, this will trap with illegal instruction exception.

Answer (score 1):

I use a second small .so library that I've written to check if a CPU supports NEON at all. After checking, I decide in java which version of my library I have to load, one built with full NEON support, one without NEON support at all: This is the code, grabbed from the NDK documentation:

```
JNIEXPORT JNICALL int Java_xypackagename_base_detectCPU_isNeon( JNIEnv* _env, jobject thiz )
{
    uint64_t features;

    if (android_getCpuFamily() != ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_ARM)
    {
        __android_log_write( ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "detectCPU", "Processor is NOT an ARM processor" );
        return 0;
    }

    __android_log_write( ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "detectCPU", "Processor is an ARM processor" );

    features = android_getCpuFeatures();

    __android_log_print( ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "detectCPU", "Processor features: %u", (unsigned int)features );

    if ((features & ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_ARMv7) == 0)
    {
        __android_log_write( ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "detectCPU", "Processor is NOT an ARM v7" );
        return 0;
    }

    __android_log_write( ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "detectCPU", "Processor is an ARM v7" );

    if ((features & ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_NEON) == 0)
    {
        __android_log_write( ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "detectCPU", "Processor has NO NEON support" );
        return 0;
    }

    __android_log_write( ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "detectCPU", "Processor has NEON support" );

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is used in the the official Hello-Neon-Example:

**Android.mk:**

```
# inside a module:

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helloneon.c

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_NEON=1
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += helloneon-intrinsics.c.neon
endif

#...
```

**Some C/C++ source file:**

```
/* HAVE_NEON is defined in Android.mk */
#ifdef HAVE_NEON
    callNeonFunc();
#else
    callStandardFunc();
#endif
```